# OpenLayers hide layer function

Tags: openlayers-2

I need to hide a layer with a function, use this script:

```
function hideLayer(layerName) {
        layerName.setVisibility(false);
}
```

I have this error: `'map' is null or undefined`

my code page:

```
var map;
var lon =9.10;
var lat =45.46;
var zoom =10;
function init(){ 
    epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {displayProjection:epsg4326,
    controls: [
        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
        ]
    });
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Mappa locale", "Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19, alpha: false, isBaseLayer: true});
 map.addLayer(newLayer);
 var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Mezzi disponibili", {
   strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor: 1.1})],                    
   protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
       url: "./sinottico_mezziliberi.txt",
       format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
        })
    });
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you indent your code better you could find the errors easier.

Your correct code would be:

```
var map;
var lon =9.10;
var lat =45.46;
var zoom =10;

function init(){ 
    epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
        displayProjection:epsg4326,
        controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
        ]
    });
}
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Mappa locale", "Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19, alpha: false, isBaseLayer: true});
map.addLayer(newLayer);

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Mezzi disponibili", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor: 1.1})],                   
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "./sinottico_mezziliberi.txt",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
    })
});
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does not contain the part where you call the function hideLayer()
so it's hard to guess why it does not work for you.

Probably just because your init()function ends before the layers are added to the map.
This would be the version which includes the creation of the two layers:

```
function init(){ 
    epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
        displayProjection:epsg4326,
        controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
            new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
        ]
    });

// init ended here

var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Mappa locale", "Tiles/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19, alpha: false, isBaseLayer: true});
map.addLayer(newLayer);

var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Mezzi disponibili", {
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({resFactor: 1.1})],                   
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
        url: "./sinottico_mezziliberi.txt",
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.Text()
    })
});
map.addLayer(layer);

// new End of init function
}
```

I set up a working jsfiddle showing how to use this function: http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/a8ck0yj9/
Just have a look at it and see if it solves your problem.

html-part:

```
<input type="button" onclick="hideLayer(vlayer)" value="Hide Layer">
```

javascript:

```
function hideLayer(layerName) {
    layerName.setVisibility(false);
}
```